# How do I reject part of an edit?

Tags: support, edits, suggested-edits

Someone edited [my question](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/32162). I like all of the changes except for one. Changing *...and the top row to the equipment inside...* to *...and the top row of the equipment inside...* actually changes the meaning of the sentence to something that isn't what I intended.

Is there a way for me to reject only part of a change or at least comment on the change? Just rejecting the edit wholesale and making the editor post a meta-question asking why it was rejected seems like putting a lot of work on someone who helped me out and got 90% of it right.

Comment: Accept and edit, or reject and edit.

Comment: @alexolut The edit was already accepted by someone else.

Comment: Honestly the other changes are just so minor and small I'd just reject the edit and re-apply the changes you want to keep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible. You can either Reject the edit (because you're the author of post, you can do so after the edit review) and apply the changes you do like, or simply edit the post and undo the change you don't like.

Comment: It used to be possible to reject an edit and apply some of its changes easily, back when there was just one "Improve" option: you could simply uncheck the "suggested edit was helpful" box.

Comment: @gparyani I think the change was because that tick box didn't always get used as intended so it was changed to be a more explicit "approve and edit"  (helpful ticked) or "reject and edit" (helpful not ticked)

Comment: @JonClements But the "Reject and Edit" option does not prefill it with the suggested revision; one needs to click "Improve Edit", select all and copy, go back, select "Reject and Edit", paste in the Markdown, and apply the changes. That's a tedious process.

Comment: @gparyani Ahhh... Yes. Been a while since I've been in the suggested edit queue to do anything but quickly reject totally inappropriate edits.

Comment: So given those two options, if I reject the edit, will the editor get reputation? Seems like the second option is nicer to the editor.

Comment: No, they will not. My recommendation: if the editor is a registered user, decide carefully if you think they deserve the rep for an approved edit. If they are an anonymous user, just choose the more convenient option, since no rep is being awarded.